# How to direct different users to different pages after login?

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication

I created a database (following an online tutorial) which directs all users to one login page. I was wondering how can I direct different users to different webpages. For example I want to direct JOHN SMITH (user1) to localhost/pages/johnsmith.html and JANE SMITH (user 2) to localhost/pages/janesmith.html.

Code:

db_const.php

```
<?php
# mysql db constants DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME
const DB_HOST = 'localhost';
const DB_USER = 'root';
const DB_PASS = 'root';
const DB_NAME = 'ClientDashboard';
?>
```

login.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>User Login Form - PHP MySQL Ligin System | W3Epic.com</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>User Login Form - PHP MySQL Ligin System | W3Epic.com</h1>
 <?php
  if (!isset($_POST['submit'])){


 ?>
<!-- The HTML login form -->
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
<?php
  } else {
require_once("db_const.php");
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
# check connection
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
    exit();
}



$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE username LIKE '{$username}' AND password LIKE '{$password}' LIMIT 1";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
if (!$result->num_rows == 1) {
    echo "<p>Invalid username/password combination</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>Logged in successfully</p>";
    // do stuffs
}
}
?>      
</body>
</html>
```

register.php

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>User registration form- PHP MySQL Ligin System | W3Epic.com</title>
</head>
 <body> 
  <h1>User registration form- PHP MySQL Ligin System | W3Epic.com</h1>
 <?php
require_once("db_const.php");
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
?>  <!-- The HTML registration form -->
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
    First name: <input type="text" name="first_name" /><br />
    Last name: <input type="text" name="last_name" /><br />
    Email: <input type="type" name="email" /><br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
<?php
} else {
## connect mysql server
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
# check connection
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli-   >connect_error}</p>";
    exit();
}
 ## query database
# prepare data for insertion
$username   = $_POST['username'];
$password   = $_POST['password'];
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name  = $_POST['last_name'];
$email      = $_POST['email'];

# check if username and email exist else insert
$exists = 0;
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT username from users WHERE username =   '{$username}' LIMIT 1");
if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
    $exists = 1;
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT email from users WHERE email =   '{$email}' LIMIT 1");
    if ($result->num_rows == 1) $exists = 2;    
} else {
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT email from users WHERE email = '{$email}' LIMIT 1");
    if ($result->num_rows == 1) $exists = 3;
}

if ($exists == 1) echo "<p>Username already exists!</p>";
else if ($exists == 2) echo "<p>Username and Email already exists!  </p>";
else if ($exists == 3) echo "<p>Email already exists!</p>";
else {
    # insert data into mysql database
    $sql = "INSERT  INTO `users` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`) 
            VALUES (NULL, '{$username}', '{$password}', '{$first_name}', '{$last_name}', '{$email}')";

    if ($mysqli->query($sql)) {
        //echo "New Record has id ".$mysqli->insert_id;
        echo "<p>Registred successfully!</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}  </p>";
        exit();
        }
    }
 }
?>      
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I take it that this isn't intended to go live, *right?* Least, I sure hope not.

Comment: What if JOHNS  MITH creates an account? He would have the same page as JOHN  SMITH.

Comment: The first and last name are never unique enough to be used as user identifier.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am a newbie and I am just experimenting :) However, I would appreciate if you could give me your thoughts why this shouldn't go live! Thanks.

Comment: @ancad first thing first, never use user inputs in your sql query together without sanitation, if you don't want to get hacked by a simple sql injection, you can start from there..

Comment: use a prepared statement and store passwords using `password_hash()` and retrieved with `password_verify()`; you can't go wrong with those ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some security concerns in your query but just to answer the part you are actually asking, you can add header("Location:" . $url) will redirect to any page.

```
//if (!$result->num_rows == 1) { 
if($result->num_rows !==1){
echo "<p>Invalid username/password combination</p>";
} else {
echo "<p>Logged in successfully</p>";
// do stuffs
 header('Location:/' . $result->firstname. $result->lastname. '.html');
}
```

Comment: Then two users that share a name will share the same page.

Comment: if you look at his question, that's what he was asking for. if not $username can be used.

Comment: `For example I want to direct JOHN SMITH (user1) to localhost/pages/johnsmith.html and JANE SMITH (user 2) to localhost/pages/janesmith.html.`

Comment: @guyfawkes How to specify the user (example 'John Smith' with a username of johnsmith) in the code provided: `header('Location:/' . $result->firstname. $result->lastname. '.html');` And what if I have multiple users? Thanks.

Comment: I totally understand what you did. But I still have to make that note.

Comment: @ancad then you just need to replace `$result->firstname.$result->lastname` with `$result->username`;
@Ibu no worries. I appreciate

Comment: @ancad, according to your question as an addition to guyfawkes's answer, you also should change / to /pages/

Answer (score 0):

The most common approach here is to have some generic user page, let's say `user.php`, that receives as `$_GET` parameter the `id` of the user. Then, when a user registers, you redirect him to `user.php?id=1`, where 1 would be the id of the registered user.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @gmc

Answer (score 0):

using a switch statment would work with a header

```
switch ($userName) {
    case "JOHN SMITH":
        header('location: localhost/pages/johnsmith.html');
        break;
    case "JANE SMITH":
        header('location: localhost/pages/janesmith.html');
        break;
    default:
        header('location: /noname.html');
}
```

This is ok if you have a very few users, but if you have a lot you would want to store that user's page url and then redirect to it on a successful login

```
if(USERLOGEDIN){
    header('location: ' . $userHomePage);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment @dsadnick

Answer (score 0):

The solution sort of depends, if you are only going to have a few specified users on there, you would only have to put an if statement which redirects to the specified page in login.php, something like:

```
if (username == 'Whatever the username might be') {
    Header("Location: file.html");
} elseif (username == 'Some other user') {
    Header("Location: file2.html");
} //so on
```

This would be after authenticating the password and username though, of course.

I hope this helped, I'm not sure what the solution might be if you're going for something bigger.

(If you get an error saying a header is already existing, use this:

```
ob_start();
```

right after `<?php` above the `<html>` tag, sometimes you might get an error if you use too many Header functions, ob start should solve this.)

Answer (score 0):

it's not entirely clear from the code where it is directed to after a correct user/pass combo is submitted.

it looks like this is the only part that does anything after verification:

```
if (!$result->num_rows == 1) {
 echo "<p>Invalid username/password combination</p>";
} else {
 echo "<p>Logged in successfully</p>";
 // do stuffs
}
```

if so, try changing it to the below code. note that this solution is required JavaScript as you have already sent headers and so a meta refresh isn't possible.

```
if (!$result->num_rows == 1) {
 echo "<p>Invalid username/password combination</p>";
} else {
 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 echo "<p>Logged in successfully</p>";
 // do stuffs
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
 echo 'window.location = "http://localhost/pages/.' .$row['first_name']. $row['last_name'].  '.htm";';
 echo '</script>';
}
}
```

also note, my code is finding the page name by pulling the first and last names from the db and merging them. You can use a more manual approach if you want but this way you don't need to edit this code to add additional users.

Comment: Thank you @digibucc . It worked. However, I want the page that the user is directed to, for example: localhost/pages/johnsmith.html to be secure as well and only accessed by the user's credentials. Is this possible?

Comment: yes you would need to verify their login on that next page. I would add a generic function to check for a session variable, and set that session variable on your login.php after logging in.